# How to handle validation errors in the view with Rails models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, error-handling, model

Looking at the [guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html) it seems like validation errors are handled by the model object's `errors` attribute so that if a validation fails, the error message goes to that attribute key in the `errors` hash. However, in my app, the validation failure results in a hard fail as in I see the exception page instead of it going back to the view. Is there something I can set to have it fail "softly"?

Comment: That means the error is not caused by a validation on the object's fields. For example, the error is not caused by something like User.name being blank. But rather by something that caused an exception, like calling a method on nil.

Comment: We won't be able to help you without more information. How are your validations setup? what does your database look like? Any database level checks, etc? How are you calling what method to cause it to fail hard?

Answer (score 0):

Alright try to find reason of failure and then try to put these statements inside ,`begin rescue` block.
Something like:

```
begin
  # iceberg
rescue
  # lifeboat
  # maybe add error in the object
  # something like: object.errors.add(:email, "Not valid")
end
```

What do think?